# How to find a value from a hidden data-preloaded element?

Tags: javascript

I just need to find a value say 'default_archetype' in the data-preloaded in the element below.

What's the best way to find the string using in Javascript?

```
<div class="hidden" id="data-preloaded" data-preloaded="{{&quot;site&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;**default_archetype**\&quot;:\&quot;regular}}}"></div>
```

Comment: Is your question how to find an element with a given string of text or, find text within a string?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I meant that I want to find if the element with the id 'data-preloaded' contains the value like default_archetype in the data-preloaded="xxxxxxx".

Comment: So you're wanting `document.getElementById`?

Comment: @mwilson I know the element ID. Using element ID, I would like to know if it contains the value in data-preloaded="xxxxxxx". It is challenging because the div does not have any value <div></div> but what I am looking for is in the <div> attribute.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: <div class="hidden" id="data-preloaded" data-preloaded="a thing I want to find is here HERE in this attribute"></div> I want to find out if the element has the thing in the attribute by using the div id which is "data-preloaded"